# What happens when I add a rectangle object in qml file?

Tags: c++, qml

What happens behind, when i add a rectangle

```
Rectangle{
 width:40
 heigh: 40
 color:"blue"

}
```

in a qml file?

What invokes what and a blue rectangle has been drawn?
What is the mechanism? Can you advise something to read, i couldnot find.
Thanks

Comment: -1 point? why?i googled really, is it a secret that nokia wants nobody to know?

Comment: It would be nice if there were a white paper on how QML works under the hood, but perhaps the reason why there is not is because it's still moving quickly. I suppose the Qt sources are the best reference at this point.. The Rectangle in this case is a QDeclarativeItem, and the "canvas" that you are drawing on is probably a QDeclarativeView. You will find these in /src/declarative/util and /src/declarative/graphicsitems.

Comment: thanks fejd, Qt sources seem to be meet my need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general:

```
 -> parse Qml code 
 -> create QDeclarativeItems
 -> add to QDeclerativeView's scene
 -> call items standard slot like onCreated()
 -> call the QDeclarativeItems paint method etc
```

You will get a warm belly feeling once you type QGraphicsRectItem into assistant-qt4 (the primary qt documentation assistant) and later realize that your qml code "Rectangle" is finally creating one. The Qt4 QtQuick implementation is currently a thin abstraction of QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene. As above, the steps are the same:

```
 -> create QGraphicsItems
 -> add to QGraphicsView's scene 
 -> call QGraphicsItem paint method etc
```

These classes are exceptionally well documented, and once you understand their principle you are ready to go forward and study their evolution to QDeclarative* etc. Unfortunately the documentation of the latter is somewhat lacking in certain details, but overall very useful. Surely, there is more to it - but once your realize the QtQuick evolution originating from QGraphicsView/-Scene classes, everything else is much more logical. Then, a glimpse into the source code (where documentation was lacking) will make you feel much more oriented - as you have an idea how the parsed markup is finally converging into QGraphicsItem's beeing created in your QGraphicsScene (QDeclarativeView,..).

Good Luck!